# What is the best alternative for a concurrent task queue, not using .net 4.0

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, queue

I'm trying to implement a framework for working with multiple cores in *Unity* applications.

What I have so far is a [non-blocking queue](http://www.boyet.com/Articles/LockfreeQueue.html) implemented by *Julian M Bucknal*. It seems to work very well for my purposes. I've created a task class, and a result class, and use two queues to distribute and collect the work which is processed on the secondary threads.

The remaining issue is that since this code is going to be used a lot in performance critical sections of my application, I would really like to minimize the use of the garbage collector.

Is there a known library / template / technique that could help me make this improvement?

```
using System.Threading;

public class LockFreeQueue<T> {
    internal struct SingleLinkNode<U> where U : T {
        // Note; the Next member cannot be a property since
        // it participates in many CAS operations
        public SingleLinkNode<U> Next;
        public U Item;
    }
    static private bool CAS<V>(ref V location, V comparand, V newValue) where V : class {
        return
            (object) comparand ==
            (object) Interlocked.CompareExchange<V>(ref location, newValue, comparand);
    }

    SingleLinkNode<T> head;
    SingleLinkNode<T> tail;

    public LockFreeQueue() {
        head = new SingleLinkNode<T>();
        tail = head;
    }

    public void Enqueue(T item) {
        SingleLinkNode<T> oldTail = null;
        SingleLinkNode<T> oldTailNext;

        SingleLinkNode<T> newNode = new SingleLinkNode<T>();
        newNode.Item = item;

        bool newNodeWasAdded = false;
        while (!newNodeWasAdded) {
            oldTail = tail;
            oldTailNext = oldTail.Next;

            if (tail == oldTail) {
                if (oldTailNext == null)
                    newNodeWasAdded = CAS<SingleLinkNode<T>>(ref tail.Next, null, newNode);
                else
                    CAS<SingleLinkNode<T>>(ref tail, oldTail, oldTailNext);
            }
        }
        CAS<SingleLinkNode<T>>(ref tail, oldTail, newNode);
    }

    public bool Dequeue(out T item) {
        item = default(T);
        SingleLinkNode<T> oldHead = null;

        bool haveAdvancedHead = false;
        while (!haveAdvancedHead) {

            oldHead = head;
            SingleLinkNode<T> oldTail = tail;
            SingleLinkNode<T> oldHeadNext = oldHead.Next;

            if (oldHead == head) {
                if (oldHead == oldTail) {
                    if (oldHeadNext == null) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    CAS<SingleLinkNode<T>>(ref tail, oldTail, oldHeadNext);
                } else {
                    item = oldHeadNext.Item;
                    haveAdvancedHead = CAS<SingleLinkNode<T>>(ref head, oldHead, oldHeadNext);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public T Dequeue() {
        T result;
        Dequeue(out result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, if you were looking for a good reason to move to .NET 4 then you found one.  This question was asked half a decade too late.

Comment: I guess *Unity* has a dozen reasons not to do that... but I wish they could.

Comment: Hmm... if I had a non-blocking stack, which didn't produce much garbage... I could use it to solve the issue by using object pooling (I think).

Comment: Have you actually tried to use this and determined that its use of memory actually causes a problem? It sounds to me as though you're just assuming that it's going to cause GC issues. Seems like you should give it a try and then if you have performance issues, profile your code and see where the problem lies. I strongly suspect that this won't be a problem.

Comment: Yes, in Unity there is a physics loop which runs at ~50 iterations per second... and I tried to add 1000 tasks per iteration and got my performance boost... but the garbage collector fired once every 1-2 seconds. The garbage collector in Unity sometimes causes small drops in framerate... it's especially a problem on platforms that doesn't support mono, for which the code is aot-compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to minimize the garbage collection by reusing instances of `SingleLinkNode<T>`.

Here's my customized non-blocking stack:

```
using System.Threading;

public class LockFreeLinkPool<T> {

    private SingleLinkNode<T> head;

    public LockFreeLinkPool() {
        head = new SingleLinkNode<T>();
    }

    public void Push(SingleLinkNode<T> newNode) {
        newNode.Item = default(T);
        do {
            newNode.Next = head.Next;
        } while (!SyncMethods.CAS<SingleLinkNode<T>>(ref head.Next, newNode.Next, newNode));
        return;
    }

    public bool Pop(out SingleLinkNode<T> node) {
        do {
            node = head.Next;
            if (node == null) {
                return false;
            }
        } while (!SyncMethods.CAS<SingleLinkNode<T>>(ref head.Next, node, node.Next));
        return true;
    }
}
```

I carefully clean all the instances `SingleLinkNode` before and after storage. This has some very cool implications for our usage of threads in *Unity*.

Comment: Hmm... does reusing the links expose me to the ABA problem?

Comment: Yes... this introduces the ABA problem, since links **have to** be compared based on reference equality :-(

Comment: Scratch that... the ABA problem would occur when an element that a thread is working on can be read+removed+reintroduced by other threads. In my case with pooling of links, the threads have exclusive access to the links while working with them. This makes me happy :-)